# How to return different values

Tags: javascript, jquery

How Jquery can chain and return multiple values?

I know you can **chain**:

```
const $ = {
    a() {
        return this;
    }
    b() {
        return this;
    }
}

$.a().b()
```

The example below will speaks by itself:

```
$('div').find('p').hide().css() // find an apply style
$('div').find('p') // return all the "p"
```

See my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/4ao5n5Lj/1/)

How jQuery return all the `p` and keep the plugin instance?

How can I achieve the same behavior?

**How to know if there is another call after `find()`?**

Thanks.

Comment: `.find` doesn't return your typical array, instead it returns a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery follows an approach like this one:

```js
function $(param) {
  if(!(this instanceof $))             // if $ is called without using 'new'
    return new $(param);               // then return a new instance
    
  this.param = param;                  // ...
}

$.prototype.a = function() {           // the function a has to...
  // a's logic
  console.log("this is a");
  return this;                         // return this so there will be chaining
}

$.prototype.b = function() {           // the same goes for b
  // b's logic
  console.log("this is b");
  return this;
}

$.c = function() {
    // c's logic
    console.log(c);
    // not returning this as c can't be chained
}

$("some param").a().b().a();
```

In the example, `a` and `b` are methods (attached to the prototype) that return `this` so they can be chained (example of `$(...).val()`, `$(...).addClass()`). `c` however is attached as a property to the function object `$` directly, thus it can't be chained (example of `$.isArray()` and `$.each()` not to be confused with `$(...).each()`).

**A mini-jQuery example:**

```js
function $(selector) {
  if(!(this instanceof $))
    return new $(selector);
    
  if(selector instanceof $)                             // if selector is already an instance of $ then just return it to be used as it is
    return selector;
  else if(typeof selector === "string")                 // otherwise, if selector is a string, then select the elements
    this.elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  else if($.isArray(selector))                          // otherwise, if the selector is an array, then the elements will be those in the array ( this is used by find )
    this.elems = selector;
  else if(!selector)                                    // otherwise, selector is a DOM element
    this.elems = [selector];
}

$.prototype.each = function(callback) {                // take a function (callback) and call it on all elements
  for(var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)           // for each element in this.elems
    callback.call(this.elems[i], i, this.elems[i]);    // call callback, setting its this to the current element and passing to it two parameters: the index and the element itself
    
  return this;
}

$.prototype.css = function(prop, value) {              // a function that take a CSS property and probably a value and either set or return the value of that CSS property
  if(value === undefined)                              // if the value is not provided, then
    return this.elems[0].style[prop];                  // return the value of the first element in the selection (some checking if the element exist should be here)
  return this.each(function() {                        // if a value is provided, then 
    this.style[prop] = value;                          // set the style of each element in the selection, and then return this (this.each returns this so just return this.each())
  });
}

$.prototype.text = function(val) {                     // follows the same as css above
  if(val === undefined)
    return this.elems[0].textContent;
  return this.each(function() {
    this.textContent = val;
  });
}

$.isArray = function(obj) {                            // is not a method (this is not the instance of the class)
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";
}


// FIND:
$.prototype.find = function(selector) {
  var newElems = [];                                    // the array of new elements
  this.each(function() {                                // for each element in the current selection
    var thisElems = this.querySelectorAll(selector);    // select it descendants that match the selector
    for(var i = 0; i < thisElems.length; i++)           // add them to the result array
      newElems.push(thisElems[i]);
  });
  // remove duplicates                                  // this is important as elements could be selected twice (elements inside a parent inside a grand parent where both parent and grand parent are in the old selection), check jQuery's source code for how they remove duplicats using sort
  return $(newElems);                                   // return a new $ object using the new array of elements as the wrapped elements (check the constructor for more informations)
}



// usage:

$("div").css("background", "#fd8")  // selects all divs and change their background
  .find("span")                     // now find all spans inside those divs
  .css("background", "#0ff");       // change their background
```

```html
<div>a</div>
<div class="even"><span>b</span></div>
<div>c</div>
<div class="even">d</div>
<div><span>e</span></div>
<span>outer span</span>
```

Comment: Thanks but I already know that. My question is more how to use the `.find()` function. The `find()` function can return all the elements `$('p').find('a')` and also be chainable:  `$('p').find('a').css(...)`. How do I know there is a next call? (chainable)

Comment: @jonathandion check the new edition. I've added the code for `find`, check the `constructor` as well (it's changed too so `find` could work).

Comment: I fix my problem I'm now using a global variable but your answer is good.

Answer (score 3):

All of these API members are returning a `jQuery` object. It just so happens that the `jQuery` API has all of these members on it. That is how you are able to chain calls on the same object.

Taking a look at the docs:

> In API calls that return jQuery, the value returned will be the original jQuery object unless otherwise documented by that AP

[`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) returns a `jQuery` type

[`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) returns a `jQuery` type

[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) returns a `jQuery` type

Note that [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) doesn't return a `jQuery` type, so you can't chain off that.

Comment: _Note that css() doesn't return a jQuery type..._. No, it does return a jQuery object if you're using it to set CSS properties. `attr`, `val` follow the same rules as `css`. `.css("background", "red")` sure returns a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks mario but how can I do the same thing using this example : https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/4ao5n5Lj/1/

Comment: Can't you just use the `$.each`? 
    $.each($('.test').find('a'), function(index, value) {
        $(value).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
     });

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir as i said, it doesnt return a `jQuery` in the context of this question, or in the way I typed it out.